# LOR designation wrongly put?

Tags: graduate-admissions, recommendation-letter

One of my references for MS grad applications has submitted the LOR undersigning as **"Assistant Senior Professor."**
Is the undersigning incorrect? and will it hamper my overall application?

She is an Assistant Professor but on a senior scale.

Thanks.

Comment: did you read the letter of reference?

Comment: Actually she said that she wrote this designation.

Comment: I have a feeling it's not correct or maybe I am overthinking

Answer (score 2):

Letter writers should use accurate titles. If her university thinks this is valid, then it is. Others may be puzzled about it, but that shouldn't affect your application. I doubt it will be a concern in any meaningful way.

Titles vary widely.